# How can I see which unit tests test a specific class?

Tags: apex, unit-test, developer-console, ide

I have test coverage for all classes but how can I see what exact unit test class provides the test coverage for that class?

Let's say I have a class: AttachmentsController - how can I see where that class is tested if I don't have any unit test class like AttachmentsControllerTest?

Answer (score 2):

Step 1 : Go to apex test execution and run all the test classes

Step 2 : Go to developer console and open the apex class and you can able to see all the test class as shown below

> To view line-by-line code coverage for an Apex class, open the class.
> The Code Coverage menu will include one or more of the following
> options depending on the tests you have implemented: None
>
> All Tests: The percentage of code coverage from all test runs.
>
> className.methodName: The percentage of code coverage from a method
> executed during a test run.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open Developer Console, click on the Tests tab and then double click on an Apex class. The code coverage menu let's you see which test classes were used in the coverage of the class.

This only works if you have recently run unit tests with code coverage enabled.